# Multiple lines with sys.argv?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, command-line

I'm trying to process some text in Python 2.7 in Windows Command Prompt with sys.argv. The purpose of the test is to reformat it removing punctuation and newlines.

```
from this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Quisque eget ligula mauris. 

to this:
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit quisque eget ligula mauris
```

However, some of the input text might be over two lines (it's pasted in from another source) and I get an error (last line of text is not recognized as an internal or external command)

```
import sys
if sys.argv[1:]:
  ask = str(sys.argv[1:])
 print ask
```

Update: As this has been pointed out it's not a Python problem, it's windows DOs box problem.

So I'll adjust my question is it possible to paste multiple line text into Python via Windows commad console for processing (without having to save it to a text file as an iterim stage) Or does this approach need rethinking?

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. It’s a question of your shell and how to create multi line commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and purpose are not clear. But I suppose you save your code in a script file like readline.py and then call that from the command line with your parameter where there are line breaks in your text. You can use ^ befor you start new line in your command line parameter. Suppose your text are as below -

> Twinkle, twinkle, little star
>   How I wonder what you are
>   Up above the world so high
>   Like a diamond in the sky

Write the line this way -

> Twinkle, twinkle, little star^
>   How I wonder what you are^
>   Up above the world so high^
>   Like a diamond in the sky^

So from Windows Command Prompt -

```
python readline.py Twinkle, twinkle, little star^  
How I wonder what you are^  
Up above the world so high^  
Like a diamond in the sky^
```